# Android install each layout like application

Tags: android

I make android application with two layouts, when I export project, and install it on phone and tablet I got two icons in menu, first open main layout, when I start second icon it open second layout

Is problem in layout calling, I make two classes for layout.

How I can solve this? thanx

Comment: You can try looking at logcat output as well to find out what's wrong. `adb logcat` from command line, or Eclipse: `Window/Show View/Other.../Android/LogCat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in manifest file.
When you declare activity u sign all activity with

```
 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" 
                     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                     android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

But this code using only for first activity^ next must declare only like:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".YourClass"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
           >
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to call new activity ..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, NewActivityToOpen.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Also don't forgot to define same over `AndroidManifest.xml` .. :)

```
<application ...>
    <activity android:name=".YourCurrentActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".NewActivityToOpen" />
```

You may need to put the fully qualified java classname to `android:name`.